# Google Chrome Isn't Working

Tags: google-chrome, launcher, icons

I downloaded google-chrome-stable awhile ago and it was working perfectly. Until one day when I clicked on the Chrome icon it flashed like it usually does(in the launcher) but then it stopped after 5 seconds and disappeared. I've tries removing it then reinstalling it, doesn't open. Does anyone know why after I click on the Chrome icon it acts like its opening by flashing but after like 5 seconds never opens???

Ubuntu 17.04 and newest version of Chrome

I tried running it in terminal it said:

> Gkr-Message:secret service operation failed: The name
>   org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files

Comment: the version of Ubuntu, and version of Chrome would be helpful in order to help you.

Comment: Try to start `google-chrome-stable` from the command line and see what error messages are printed.

Comment: Type `command -v gnome-keyring`. If the output is empty , do `apt-get install gnome-keyring`. Maybe it's missing.

Answer (score 1):

`google-chrome-stable` didnt work,  After install `gnome-keyring` it perfectly worked for me running as `google-chrome-stable` or `google-chrome`