# Chromium not starting on VNC remote desktop on 16.04

Tags: xfce, chromium, vnc

I read about the documented bug with Chromium on multiple displays, but I am not sure this is my problem. I have Ubuntu Server 16.04 as file server for a small Windows10 home network. I am running xfce4 on server and tightVNC server with tightVNC viewer on Win10 Remote Desktop. The session is working fine headless.

I installed Chromium browser and it started the 1st time, but it will not start after the 1st time. Now, the browser that came with xfce4 will not start either.

I autoremoved Chromium browser and re-installed it to no avail. When I start Chrome from command line, I get the following error:

```
$ /usr/bin/chromium-browser
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "RANDR" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1.0".
Xlib:  extension "XInputExtension" missing on display ":1.0".
[8579:8579:1113/131313.273941:ERROR:gl_surface_glx.cc(414)] glxQueryVersion failed
[8579:8579:1113/131313.273978:ERROR:gl_initializer_x11.cc(153)] GLSurfaceGLX::InitializeOneOff failed.
[8579:8579:1113/131313.275682:ERROR:gpu_child_thread.cc(254)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[8529:8562:1113/131313.278020:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(108)] Failed to launch GPU process.
Gkr-Message: secret service operation failed: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

Is this the documented bug with Chrome and multiple Xservers or something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Chrome Isn't Working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/964801/google-chrome-isnt-working)